# EF Core - How to override PK convention for all guids to be non clustered

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want to be able to override the PK generated for all entities that use a Guid as PK and set to be non clustered.

I also want to be able to add a convention for all entities that inherit a base type of X and create a clustered index on a known property that X has.

I just started looking at the convention stuff in EF Core 7 and it's a lot to take in.

(This does not include "don't use Guid for PK" :-) )

Comment: I would then recommend letting each entity define its own PK based on the unique values it can use for a clustered index, and let the base type define a unique, inon-clustered ndex-able value that all entities/tables share that is *not* the PK. While there are certainly cases where you can have non-clustered PK indexes, employing that for all FK relationships isn't recommended. Many databases support index-friendly UUID formatting (I.e. SequentialGuid) which when combined with regular index maintenance jobs can allow Guids to play nicely within a clustered index.

Comment: Thanks Steve. But do you know how to answer the OP and override the conventions?
Just so you are aware, I am following some of Microsofts advice (from 2010) about using guids as PK:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/uniqueidentifier-and-clustered-indexes/#:~:text=Clustering%20and%20uniqueidentifier,orders%20a%20clustered%20index%20sequentially.

Comment: Although Azure sql by the looks of it does support sequential UUID now :-)

Comment: In that case, why not use sequential UUIDs? Making the PK non-clustered won't fix the problems caused by using UUIDs. The *PK index* will still be fragmented, even if the data isn't. Retrieving entries that were made close together will still require hopping around

Comment: Thanks Steve and Panagiotis. I did end up using sequential uuids. Which have helped performance.
I did still want to know how to do the actions above purely from a learning curve perspective